# "and not re.search" multiple conditions

Tags: python, regex

I'm working on part a python script and I've come across a situation that I have not been able to figure out. In this part, I've opened a file and initially targeting lines that start with `>`. However, I want to skip over those lines that have the following regex patterns:

```
uce.+$
ENSOFAS.+$
_[AB]_[0-9]+$
_[AB]_[0-9]+_rc$
```

if my code looks like the following, targeting just one of these, it works:

```
with open(company_fn, "r") as company_fh:
    for line in company_fh:
        if line.startswith('>') and not re.search('uce.+$', line.strip()):
            print line
```

But I need it to consider all the other possiblities too. I've tried ...`not re.search(('uce.+$ | ENSOFAS.+$'), line.strip()):`, `not re.search(('uce.+$' | 'ENSOFAS.+$'), line.strip()):`, and other variants on this with no success. How can I get re.search to consider all four possible regex expressions?

Comment: `'uce.+$ | ENSOFAS.+$'`: don't add spaces around pipes. Also the other examples creates logicial operation on strings... (see the quotes on `re.search(('uce.+$' | 'ENSOFAS.+$')`). I think you need to edit your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [regex expression to exclude lines based on beginning or ending patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47057400/regex-expression-to-exclude-lines-based-on-beginning-or-ending-patterns) (same user)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
not re.search(('uce.+$ | ENSOFAS.+$'), line.strip())
```

Don't add "spaces for clarity" when oring regexes together, because they are taken into account. That works:

```
not re.search('uce.+$|ENSOFAS.+$',line.strip())
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Regarding the other patterns, my understanding is those strings are also being searched for. It works during searches, just doesn't work when I try including it with the others. I just need that line skipped if it ends in anything with an A or B and any number of digits at the end of the line (or in some cases with an additional rc); each of these are separated by underscores.

Comment: Apparently removing the beginning underscore for those other two solves the problem, though I have no idea why.

Comment: you didn't provide any input or expected output in detail. I had to guess.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to use the newer [**`regex`**](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex/) module, you could define exceptions like so:

```
import regex as re

string = """
uce123
ENSOFAS123
_A_123
_B_123_rc
this line should be matched
"""

exceptions = [r'uce.+$', r'ENSOFAS.+$', r'_[AB]_[0-9]+$', r'_[AB]_[0-9]+_rc$']

rx = re.compile(r'(?:{})(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|(.+)'.format("|".join(exceptions)), re.MULTILINE)

lines = rx.findall(string)
print(lines)
# ['this line should be matched']
```

Essentially, this sets up an array `exceptions` which is joined in the overall expression afterwards.